# CompletableFuture thread will ever be closed if I don't call .join() method?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, java-threads

```
CompletableFuture retrunsVal = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    //some logic
    return new Object();
});

CompletableFuture notRetrunsVal = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    //some logic
});
```

With my current understanding, if I don't call `retrunsVal.join();` then the thread opened in the first call will never be closed as long as the server is up, but even if I don't call `notRetrunsVal.join();` on the second call, the opened thread will get closed as soon as it did with the execution.

Please let me know if I have the correct understanding.

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of [`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier)):

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the [ForkJoinPool.commonPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()) with the value obtained by calling the given Supplier.

It uses a thread pool in the background. This means that both futures can run in different threads.

If you wait for the first future to finish and then run the second future after it finishes, it might use the same thread because it is reused but it can also use a different thread.

As the thread pool belongs to a JVM instance, it will be closed when the JVM is closed so when a JVM is stopped, the thread pool will also be stopped.

From the docs of [ForkJoinPool.commonPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()):

> Returns the common pool instance. This pool is statically constructed; its run state is unaffected by attempts to shutdown() or shutdownNow(). However this pool and any ongoing processing are automatically terminated upon program System.exit(int). Any program that relies on asynchronous task processing to complete before program termination should invoke commonPool().awaitQuiescence, before exit.

The thread pool used for [`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier)) will stay alive as long as the JVM stays alive.

The only thing that [`.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()) is waiting for a future to complete, this does not close anything.

Comment: I apologize if my question confused you, but what I meant to ask is, how they behave if they called individually, it could be one is on 'A' JVM and another one is on 'B' JVM, and if I don't call .join() in both cases, will opened threads will ever be closed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about closure of open threads, i believe you can use

runAsync(Runnable runnable, Executor executor)
and
supplyAsync(Supplier supplier, Executor executor) APIs of CompletableFuture. Both of these APIs expects executor on which you want to execute your task.